# What if $X_k(\omega)$ isn't uniformly bounded for $\omega$?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, summation, martingales, stopping-times

From Williams' Probability with Martingales (don't mind the red boxes).

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Which part doesn't hold if $|X_k(\omega)| \le K \forall k$ but not $\forall \omega$? I guess $K$ and maybe $c$ are random, but so what? We'll just let $c$ and $K$ be positive a.s.

Comment: If $|X_k|$ are not uniformly bounded then the result does not necessarily hold. The problem is that when $T=\infty$ there is no guarantee that $E(A_{T\wedge n}) $ is bounded, since the bound for $E(A_{T\wedge n}) $ would potentially depend on $T$.

Comment: @clark okay fine thanks. $c$, $k$ are positive a.s. and bounded. Ok now?

Answer (score 1):

Consider an independent sequence $\left(X_k\right)_{k\geqslant 1}$ such that 
$$
\Pr\left(X_k=k^2\right)=\frac1{2k^2}=\Pr\left(X_k=-k^2\right); \Pr\left(X_k=0\right)=\frac1{k^2}.
$$
Since $\sum_{k\geqslant 0}\Pr\left(X_k\neq 0\right)<+\infty$, the Borel-Cantelli lemma ensures the almost sure convergence of $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}X_k$. But $\sigma_k^2=1$ for all $k\geqslant 1$ hence the series $\sum_{k=1}^{+\infty}\sigma_k^2$ cannot converge.

Comment: Ah thanks. Which part exactly doesn't hold please? And for what conditions would we still have the result?